# форматирование строчных данных в python: удалить справа 4 символа (сохранить до дефиса)

Tags: python, строки

Здравствуйте, простой вопрос: вывожу данные с API, получаю : ETR-BCT

Нужно из этих символов сделать ETR - то есть удалить справа 4 символа, для вставки получившегося в другой запрос.

Как это сделать с помощью "%" или "format"?

Comment: Почему вам надо сделать это именно с помощью форматирования?

Comment: Тогда, как иначе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
src = 'ETR-BCT'
dst = src.split('-')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про срезы https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html

```
>>> s = 'ETR-BCT'
>>> s[:-4]
'ETR'
```

Comment: `s[:3]` более прямой метод, если формат фиксированный.

Answer (score 1):

Используя [`str.partition` метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> s = 'a-b-c'
>>> s.partition('-')
('a', '-', 'b-c')
```

Или если вы уверены, что строка содержит `'-'`:

```
>>> s = 'a-b-c'
>>> s[:s.index('-')]
'a'
```